# Writing a group element as $ghg^{-1} h^{-1}$ and as $g^2 h^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, alternative-proof

I recently read the elegant paper [Generalized Frobenius Schur Numbers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.79.8077), by Bump and Ginzburg, which I learned about [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126828/irreducible-degrees-and-the-order-of-a-finite-group). The results in this paper imply the following:

> Let $G$ be a finite group where every element is conjugate to its inverse. Then, for any $x \in G$, the number of ways to write $x$ as $ghg^{-1} h^{-1}$ is equal to the number of ways to write $x$ as $g^2 h^2$.

I'll give the proof below, using character theory. I tried to find an elementary proof and failed. Can you do it?

---

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$We need to prove the equality $\sum_{g, h \in G} g^2 h^2 = \sum_{g, h \in G} g h g^{-1} h^{-1}$ in $\CC[G]$. Since we have $\CC[G] \cong \bigoplus_V \mathrm{End}(V)$, where the sum is over irreps of $V$, it is enough to show that both group elements act the same way on each $V$.

As I computed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243221/proofs-that-the-degree-of-an-irrep-divides-the-order-of-a-group), $\sum_{g, h \in G} ghg^{-1} h^{-1}$ acts on an irrep $V$ by $\left( \frac{|G|}{\dim V} \right)^2$.

Now consider $\sum_{g \in G} g^2$ acting on an irrep $V$. Since $\sum_{g \in G} g^2$ is central in $\CC[G]$, it must act by a scalar, and computing traces we find that this scalar is $\frac{1}{\dim V} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_V(g^2)$. The quantity $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_V(g)^2$ is known as the [Frobenius-Schur indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) and is $\pm 1$ for a group where every element is conjugate to its inverse. So $\sum_{g \in G} g^2$ acts on $V$ by $\pm \frac{|G|}{dim V}$
and
$\left( \sum_{g \in G} g^2 \right)^2$ acts on $V$ by $\left( \frac{|G|}{\dim V} \right)^2$.

We have shown that $\sum_{g, h \in G} ghg^{-1} h^{-1}$ and $\left( \sum_{g \in G} g^2 \right)^2 = \sum_{g,h \in G} g^2 h^2$ act on every irrep by the same scalar, so they are equal in the group algebra. QED.

---

The same argument shows that, in any finite group, the number of ways to write $x$ as $f^2 g^2 h^2$ is the same as the number of ways to write $x$ as $f^2 g h g^{-1} h^{-1}$, using that the Frob. Schur indicator is always $-1$, $0$ or $1$ and thus obeys $\epsilon^3 = \epsilon$. In case anyone finds that easier to think about...

Comment: Partial result: if $g' = aga'$ and $h' = bhb'$ (where ' is inverse), then $$ghg'h' = ghaga'bhb' = (gha)^2 (gha)'ga'bhb' = (gha)^2 a'h'a'bhb' = (gha)^2(a'bhb'a'bhb') = (gha)^2(a'bhb')^2$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $g \in G$, let $y_g$ be an element of $G$ such that $y_g g y_g^{-1} = g^{-1}$. For $g, h \in G$, let $x_{g,h} = gy_h^{-1}$.

Note that $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = (gy_h^{-1}y_h)h(gy_h^{-1}y_h)^{-1}h^{-1} = xh^{-1}x^{-1}h^{-1}$ where $x = x_{g, h}$.

Then, $$
\displaystyle\sum_{g,h} ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = \displaystyle\sum_h \displaystyle\sum_g ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \\= \displaystyle\sum_h \displaystyle\sum_g (gy_h^{-1})h^{-1}(gy_h^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}
= \displaystyle\sum_h \displaystyle\sum_g gh^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}
= \displaystyle\sum_{g, h}gh^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}
$$

We also have
$$\displaystyle\sum_{g,h} g^2h^2 = \displaystyle\sum_g \displaystyle\sum_h g^2h^2 \\ = 
\displaystyle\sum_g \displaystyle\sum_h g^2(g^{-1}h)^2 = \displaystyle\sum_g \displaystyle\sum_h ghg^{-1}h = \displaystyle\sum_{g, h} ghg^{-1}h =  \displaystyle\sum_{g, h} gh^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}$$

For any $x \in G$, $(g, h) \mapsto (gy_h, y_h^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1})$
is an explicit bijection from $\{(g, h) \in G \times G \mid ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = x\} $ to $\{(g, h)\in G \times G \mid g^{2}h^{2} = x\}$ with inverse $(g, h) \mapsto (gy_{h^{-1}g^{-1}}^{-1}, h^{-1}g^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also calculate those directly, using this [Number of ways a group element of a finite group can be written as a given word](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447984/number-of-ways-a-group-element-of-a-finite-group-can-be-written-as-a-given-word/448059#448059) and the hypothesis that every element is conjugate to it's inverse to get the result. It all comes about calculating that $\sum_{(g,h) \in G^2} \chi(g^2h^2) = \frac{|G|^2}{\chi(1)}$ for all irreducible characters $\chi$, from which the result would follow (the calculations for the commutator case are fairly simple and yield the number of ways to write $x$ to be $|G| \sum_{\chi} \frac{\chi(x)}{\chi(1)}$ where the sum is taken over all irreducible characters).