# Why does $d_{\alpha}$ divide $\#G$ for $\alpha\in\hat{G}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a unitary irreducible representation of a finite group $G$. Then we have \begin{equation}
d_{\alpha}|\#G,
\end{equation} where $d_\alpha$ is the degree of the representation and $\#G$ is the order of the group.

I learnt one proof from Barry Simon's *Representation of Finite and Compact Groups*. However his proof depends on some delicate arguments in algebraic number theory, which seems to be very surprising and not so illuminating.

I am wondering whether this is necessary because $d_{\alpha}|\#G$ seems naive enough to be proved entirely in the framework of representation theory.

I am wondering whether someone can share a hint. If there is no such proof yet, can we at least try to understand, within representation theory, why this should be true?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This question is very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243221

Comment: @DerekHolt Nice link! But it seems answers there are not really satisfactory for they also heavily use algebraic number theory.