Does an irr. rep. of finite $G$ have a basis of the form $\{hv : h \in H\}$ for $H$ subgroup of $G$?
Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ be a (complex vector space) representation of $G$. Consider the following three facts:

Whenever a $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, the dimension of $V$ must divide the order of $G$. See this stackexchange post: Proofs that the degree of an irrep divides the order of a group The proof uses the basis theory of algebraic integers.
Langrange's Theorem: Every subgroup of $G$ divides the order of $G$. (Though the converse is not true, in that if $d$ is an integer dividing the order of $G$, then there need not exist a subgroup of $G$ of size $d$.)
Whenever $V$ is a representation of a group $G$, and $v$ is any element of $V$, the set $\{ gv: g \in G \}$ spans a subrepresentation of $V$. Of course, it is natural to ask whether there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ that does this more efficiently, and in particular if there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $\{ hv: v \in H\}$ also spans $G$. This appears to be the case for some simple examples of irreducible representations (e.g. the standard representation of $S_3$ is spanned by the action of the identity and a transposition on an eigenvector of a three cycle).

It is tempting to put these facts together and ask the following question:

Question: If $V$ is an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$, does there exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ and an element $v$ of $V$ such that $\dim(V) = H$, and that $\{ hv: h \in H \}$ spans $V$?

If the answer to this question is "yes", this would give an alternative proof of Fact 1 above that circumvents the use of algebraic numbers.
Has anyone seen this question tackled in the literature? Is there a simple counterexample? If the answer is "no", can we amend the statement to say anything useful about spanning subsets of the form $\{ gv: g \in S\}$, where $S$ is any subset of $G$? How does this question pertain to the symmetric group $G = S_n$? Of course, perhaps the nontruth of the converse to Lagrange's theorem could suggest a "no" answer!
Anyway, I'd be grateful to hear an answer, reference, or any thoughts!

I've just seen that the main idea of this question is suggested in Brian Klatt's comment on this post in Fact 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243221/proofs-that-the-degree-of-an-irrep-divides-the-order-of-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1

Are you only looking at representations over $\mathbb{C}$? The statement that for $V$ irreducible, $\dim V$ divides $|G|$, is not true over arbitrary fields.

Yes, I meant only representations over $\mathbb{C}$. Good point, thanks! I've amended the statement.

@Samuel: can you clarify what you meant by "${ hv }$ is a basis of $V$"? In particular, did you really mean that set of vectors or did you mean the collection of vectors $hv, h \in H$ (with multiplicity)? In particular, did you mean for your condition to imply that the vectors are necessarily distinct, so $\dim V = |H|$?

Hi Qiaochu, good point, thanks. What I meant to say is that the set of vectors ${ hv : h \in H }$ span $V$, and that $H$ has the same cardinality as the dimension of $V$. I've edited my post to make this clear.

I think the answer to your question is no.
Say $V$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module, where $G$ is a finite group.
Let $H \leq G$, and suppose that $v \in V$ is such that $\{hv : h \in H\}$ is a basis for $V$. Then because the vector $\sum_{h \in H} hv$ is fixed by $H$, it follows that $H$ has a non-zero fixed point.
This suggests a way of finding counterexamples. You will have one if you can find a $V$ such that for all $H \leq G$, one of the following holds:

$H$ has no non-zero fixed points on $V$.
$|H| < \dim V$.

One such example is $G = Q_8$ (quaternion group) with $V$ the $2$-dimensional irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

The pair $(V, H)$ have this property iff the restriction $\text{Res}^G_H(V)$ of $V$ to a representation of $H$ is isomorphic to the regular representation of $H$. This is a very strong condition; it is equivalent to the condition that $\dim V = |H|$ and that the character $\chi_V(h)$ of $V$, when evaluated on $h \in H$, is $0$ for $h \neq e$.
So, we can find counterexamples by finding irreducible representations $V$ of finite groups $G$ (of dimension $\ge 2$) such that the character does not vanish on the non-identity elements of any subgroup of $G$ of order $\dim V$. As in testaccount's answer, the smallest counterexample appears to be the quaternion group $Q_8$: it has a unique subgroup of size $2$, namely its center $\{ \pm 1 \}$, and the character of the unique $2$-dimensional representation doesn't vanish on it. (Of course we can see pretty directly that this subgroup can't have the desired property, since it acts by a scalar on this representation.)
Interestingly it doesn't appear to be possible to produce counterexamples this way for the small alternating and symmetric groups, from an examination of their character tables.

In the first sentence, why would it be the regular representation? Couldn't $\text{Res}^G_H(V)$ be some other permutation module for $H$?

@testaccount: if the ${ hv }$ are linearly independent then the dimension of their span is exactly $|H|$, and $h$ acts on them by permutation, via the regular representation.

"if the {hv} are linearly independent then the dimension of their span is exactly |H|": Take the natural permutation module for $H = S_n$, i.e. permuting basis vectors $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$. Then ${h v_1 : h \in H} = {v_1, \ldots, v_n}$ is a basis. But the action is not regular.

@testaccount: okay, I suppose there's some ambiguity here. The way I interpreted the OP's question is that they wanted $\dim V = |H|$ so the divisibility of $|G|$ by the dimension would follow from Lagrange's theorem, so I interpreted "${ hv }$ is a basis" to mean that the vectors $hv$, not the set of vectors ${ hv }$, form a basis; this requires in particular that they are distinct. Your interpretation is more literal and would also give the desired divisibility so I guess I don't know what the OP intended and we should ask them.
